# Signal/Slots connection does not work with no warning or error

Tags: eclipse, qt, signals-slots

I'm using Eclipse with Qt and even thought I wrote a simple example, it doesn't work. The small window with a button and a QLineEdit appears, but if I push the button, it writes nothing in the QLineEdit. I'm a beginner, so I don't know if I've wrote something wrong or it just doesn't work.
I've tried the same example in Qt Designer, and I had the same result.

### main.cpp

```
#include "proj.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    proj w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

### proj.h

```
#ifndef PROJ_H
#define PROJ_H

#include <QtGui/QWidget>
#include "ui_proj.h"
#include "testUi.h"

class proj : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    proj(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~proj();

private:
    TestUi ui;
    void connection();
    void scrie();
};
#endif // PROJ_H
```

### proj.cpp

```
#include "proj.h"

proj::proj(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{ 
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connection();
}

proj::~proj(){}

void proj::connection(){
    QObject::connect(ui.btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(scrie()));
}

void proj::scrie(){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Information", ".....");
    ui.ed->setText("a scris");
}
```

### testUI.h

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include <qboxlayout.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include <qlineedit.h>
#include <qobject.h>
#include <qwidget.h>

#ifndef TESTUI_H_
#define TESTUI_H_

class TestUi{
public:
QPushButton *btn;
QLineEdit *ed;
public:
    void setupUi(QWidget *w){
        QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout;
        w->setLayout(lay);

        btn = new QPushButton;
        ed = new QLineEdit;

        lay->addWidget(btn);
        lay->addWidget(ed);
    } 
};   

#endif /* TESTUI_H_ */
```

Comment: `QObject::connect` doesn't work because `scrie` function actually isn't slot.

Comment: You should check the console output. Runtime errors like failed connections will be reported there.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems I've found in your code.

## Connection of SIGNALS and SLOTS.

Connection doesn't work because `proj::scrie` actually isn't SLOT. In order to make SLOT you have to declare `slots` section in class declaration.

```
private slots:
    void scrie();
```

Connection isn't compile time feature, so the project will compile fine even there is error. But in run-time it does some checks and should provide warnings in console like `Object::connect: No such slot proj::scrie() in proj.cpp:12`. Please check out the console output.

## Explicit constructor

Your class has the following declaration of constructor:

```
proj(QWidget *parent = 0);
```

It's good practice to declare constructor in which only one argument can be passed as `explicit`. It lets you prevent implicit conversions.

## Includes

Please, don't include Qt's header files this way:

```
#include <qboxlayout.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
#include <qlineedit.h>
#include <qobject.h>
#include <qwidget.h>
```

There is no guarantee that these headers will be available in the following versions of Qt. You should include it like this:

```
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QObject>
```

and so on.

## Include guards

You have some "include" directives placed before "include guards". It is not an error, but it would be better to place the entire body of header between guards.

## Encapsulation

Don't declare data member in public. If you want to use "private" class look at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer article.

Answer (score 0):

your `scrie()` method is meant to be a slot so you have to put the `void scrie();` declaration in .h file in `privates slots:` section and not just `private:`.